# Web audio API Audio Nodes connecting across contexts?

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I have been investigating and it seems that a window has only one audio context, every audionode has also one context so that would mean there is no way for two contexts to share the same audionode.
What i am trying to accomplish is to send audio from one window (iframe) to it's parent and vice versa. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not in a performant way, no.  You would have to have ScriptProcessor nodes in each, and use message-passing to get between them, and the latency of that would likely cause some problems.

Comment: I am actually trying to accomplish this and the funny thing is that there is barely any latency, the only tricky thing is to let the two contexts run in sync, but performance.now cannot measure any latency from the postMessage calls most of the time.